# C++ command line argument verification

Tags: c++

If provided with command line argument argv[], what is a way to determine whether or not that input is a file name.

E.g. If we are entering ex.txt into the command line, and printing out the contents, how can I write a conditional statement to determine whether the input for argv[1] is correct?

Thanks. Let me know if I was too vague. This is my first post, and english is not my first language.

Comment: Name of the file could be in many forms event without extension. You could simply check the file existence.

Comment: If your code is supposed to open a file, there is little harm in just trying.

Comment: Write 100 times "C is not C++ is not C!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to know only whether the file *exists* but also if you can open and read it.  The only reliable way (And, by the way, the only way currently supported by standard C++.) to do this is to try opening the file and see if you succeed.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


int
main(const int argc, const char *const *const argv)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
      std::ifstream istr {argv[i]};
      if (!istr)
        {
          std::cerr << "error: " << argv[i] << ": cannot read file\n";
          continue;
        }
      // Do something with the stream...
    }
}
```

Be aware that if you close the file after verifying that it is good, there is no guarantee that it will still be good if you try to open it again later.  Some other process could have deleted it or taken your permissions to read it.